# Share code between multiple Xcode+PhoneGap projects

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have created a phonegap-based app for which I would like to create several similar apps with different content but the same basic code. And I would like to have only one copy of the "base" code rather than trying to maintain multiple copies of it in different projects.

Basically each app needs a config file, a directory for some images, and a json file describing the images. But otherwise the code would be the same between all of them.

How can I accomplish this in Xcode+PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SVN or Git and have the base code that is shared as an external (SVN) or submodule (Git).

That way you are only editing the base code in one spot, then when you create each new project you just add the base code in.